# WPF Suggestion text box with MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've got a textbox in WPF which auto suggests based on an array of strings. However, I've got this in the code behind and trying to rewrite the whole thing without violating MVVM as the whole thing has become a nightmare to test. What is the best way to go about this? Is an attached behaviour to a textbox the only way?

See code I currently have below

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="Solutions.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="SuggestionBox" Width="200"
             />
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Solutions
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private static readonly string[] SuggestionValues = {
            "England",
            "USA",
            "France",
            "Estonia"
        };

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SuggestionBox.TextChanged += SuggestionBoxOnTextChanged;
        }

        private string _currentInput = "";
        private string _currentSuggestion = "";
        private string _currentText = "";

        private int _selectionStart;
        private int _selectionLength;
        private void SuggestionBoxOnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var input = SuggestionBox.Text;
            if (input.Length > _currentInput.Length && input != _currentSuggestion)
            {
                _currentSuggestion = SuggestionValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith(input));
                if (_currentSuggestion != null)
                {
                    _currentText = _currentSuggestion;
                    _selectionStart = input.Length;
                    _selectionLength = _currentSuggestion.Length - input.Length;

                    SuggestionBox.Text = _currentText;
                    SuggestionBox.Select(_selectionStart, _selectionLength);
                }
            }
            _currentInput = input;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want the string to be defined? In the view model or in the view?

Comment: In the view model

Comment: Then yes, an attached behaviour is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 options:

- attached property (which is cool, but this is a bit to complex for it in my opinion)
- create a new class `SuggestionTextBox : TextBox` with dependency property for a function that will fetch the suggestions
- go with editable ComboBox, which will work almost out of the box, but you would still have to create `SuggestionBox` class.

Creating new class gives you reausabillity and full control. I use [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/) as my MVVM framework which gives you strongly type async commands.

So, the overview of the code would be:

```cs
public class SuggestionBox : TextBox // you can easily go with ComboBox here, and even have xaml file if you want fancier UI
{
   public ReactiveCommand<string, string[]> FetchSuggestionsCommand {get;set;} // this should dependency property, left out for brevity

   public ObservableColection<string> Suggestions {get;} // also dependency property


   public SuggestionBox()
   {
       this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Text).InvokeCommand(FetchSuggestionsCommand); // this is strongly typed so you get compilation error if types don't match
       
       FetchSuggestionsCommand.Subscribe(suggestions => 
                {
                    Suggestions.Clear();
                    Suggestions.AddRange(suggestions);
                }); // a little more subscribtion management magic required, but I just want to show the idea
    // rest of your logic for displaying suggestions
    }
}
```

Then in some other XAML:

```xml
<SuggestionBox FetchSuggestionsCommand="{Binding ViewModel.FetchSuggestionsFromWeb}"/>
```

Now you nice decoupling between the fetching logic (it lives in some other ViewModel, in ReactiveUI you can even handle errors there) and the view (it lives only in the `SuggestionBox` class and does not care about the logic how to get the suggestions).

One remark at the end: having code in xaml.cs is not MVVM violation. Really, you can do cool stuff there (like setting focus to some element if something happens, having that in ViewModel is wrong). MVVM is a very cool pattern, not that restrictive once you get the hang of it the idea.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is entirely dependent on the View.
On MVVM - this is not affected.
If only a list of words, you will receive from the Model.

I would take this into a separate Attachment Property into which a collection of words is passed.
But this is more a matter of convenience, habit, rather than conformity of MVVM.

Comment: Attachment Property